# Is there any way to check the repetition of the value in a B field, taking into account a sorted A field, for each ID group? (See example below)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, group-by, sas

Suppose we have a table of thousands of users with an *ID*, a *year-month* and a *balance($)*.
Let's simplify it in the following table with 3 users:

| user ID (numeric) | year-month (string) | balance(float) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01 | 500.0 |
| 1 | 2019-02 | 500.0 |
| 1 | 2019-03 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2019-04 | 500.0 |
| 1 | 2019-05 | 0.0 |
| 1 | 2019-06 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2018-09 | 1000.0 |
| 2 | 2018-10 | 1000.0 |
| 2 | 2018-11 | 750.0 |
| 2 | 2018-12 | 500.0 |
| 2 | 2019-01 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2019-02 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2019-03 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2019-04 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2019-05 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2019-06 | 0.0 |
| 2 | 2019-07 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 2018-01 | 200.0 |
| 3 | 2018-02 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 2018-03 | 200.0 |
| 3 | 2018-04 | 0.0 |

The main rule is that: **If the balance reaches 0 in a given month, there cannot be a month afterwards where the balance value is other than 0**. This means that the only user who would have his records correctly reported would be ID=2.

As a final output, I want a table that shows me how many user IDs satisfy the rule and how many do not:

| well_informed | num_cases |
| --- | --- |
| YES | 1 |
| NO | 2 |

I have tried several things without even getting close to a result because of the difficulty of iterating through the consecutive records of a user ID and checking the condition.

A solution in both Python-Pandas and SQL is valid for the environment I am working in. Thank you very much!

**EDIT v1**: @d.b @Henry Ecker solution works fine for the example I have provided, but not for my problem because I have not specified some cases that would be valid, such as the following:

| user ID (numeric) | year-month (string) | balance(float) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2019-02 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-03 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-04 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-05 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-06 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-07 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-08 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-09 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-10 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-11 | 1000.0 |
| 4 | 2019-12 | 1000.0 |

which should be considered TRUE, but classifies it as FALSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each `ID`, perform run length encoding on `balance` and check if only the last value for that encoding is `0`.

```py
import pdrle

def foo(x):
    rle = pdrle.encode(x.eq(0))
    if rle.vals.sum() == 0:
        return True
    if rle.vals.sum() == 1:
        return rle.vals.tail(1).item()
    return False


ans = dat.groupby(dat["user ID"], as_index=False).balance.apply(foo)
ans
#     user ID     balance
# 0         1       False
# 1         2        True
# 2         3       False
```

In the next step, you can summarize `ans`

```py
ans.groupby("balance").size()
# balance
# False    2
# True     1
# dtype: int64
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your response. It works fine for the example I have put in particular, but not for my problem because I have not specified some cases that would be valid, such as the following:

Let's imagine you have a new id=4 with 5 rows, where they all have a value of $1000. The information would be correct, so it would be a **True**, but it would count it as *False*.

Could this be dealt on the code you have written?

Comment: @0xGolovkin, check now